# Analyitc Continuation of Partial $\zeta$ function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

Let $A\subset \mathbb{N}$. Consider the partial $\zeta$ function
$$\sum_{a\in A} \frac{1}{a^s}$$
We know this converges for Re$(s)>1$. Under what conditions of $A$, can this be analyically continued and what would it's analytic continuation be?

If $A =  d\mathbb{N}$, all the naturals divisible by $d$, then 
$$\sum_{a\in A}\frac{1}{a^s} = \frac{1}{d^s}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$$
and so this can be analytically continued. Moreover, we can say that
$$\sum_{a\in A}\frac{1}{a^s} - \frac{1}{d^s}\frac{1}{s-1}$$
will be holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$.

My guess would be that if 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cup\{1,\dots,n\}|}{n} = \delta>0$$
then
$$\sum_{a\in A}\frac{1}{a^s} - \frac{\delta^s}{s-1}$$
is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$.

Is this correct? Is there anything that can be said about sets with zero density?

Comment: zero density doesn't help : for example the primes have zero density, but you can imagine much more complicated subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula